# use CGPoint as an array

Tags: cgpoint

I want to use an function to pass a lot of points to another function, but the Xcode has errors on the line with:  CGContextAddLines......

the add points is filled with information like:

CGPoint addPoints[] = {
        CGPointMake(10,10),
        CGPointMake(10,10),
}

the use the 
-(void) constructPoints:(CGContextRef) context withPoints:(CGPoint) addPoints {

```
// do some context set attributes, color
// and
```

CGContextAddLines(context, addPoints, sizeof(addPoints)/sizeof(addPoints[0]));

// and draw-it

}

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
-(void) constructPoints:(CGContextRef) context withPoints:(CGPoint[]) addPoints numPoints:(int) size {
  // do some context set attributes, color
  // and 
  CGContextAddLines(context, addPoints, size);

  // and draw-it

}
```

Then on your call:

```
[self constructPoints:yourContext withPoints:addPoints numPoints:sizeof(addPoints)/sizeof(addPoints[0])];
```

Comment: Glad to be of use and feel free to accept the answer if it works for you.